# Do not close the dropdown until I select both time and date on datetime picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have an issue with datetimepicker of jQuery. I need the dropdown to not close until I select both time and date and not the date only. I want after someone selects time the dropdown should not close as it does not get closed when the date is picked, so I want the same for the time as well.

The second thing that can't resolve is: when I select the time the default date should not get selected. I have disabled the previous dates including today's date. So when a customer clicks only on time pick, default date is selected aswell which is of today that i dont want to get selected and have disabled by the way.

Here is my code:

```
var now = new Date();

now.setDate(now.getDate()+1);

 $('#datetime').datetimepicker({ 
   formatTime:'g:i A',
 minDate:now,
 disabledDates: [now],

   allowTimes:[
  '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', 
  '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00'
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onClose` of the datetimepicker. If you return `false` it wont close.

The example is not perfect, but you get the concept :)

```js
var now = new Date();

now.setDate(now.getDate()+1);

function areBothFilled() {
  console.log( $('#datetime').val() );
  console.log( $('#datetime2').val() );
  
  if( $('#datetime').val() !== "" && $('#datetime').val() !== "" ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

$('#datetime').datetimepicker({ 
    formatTime:'g:i A',
    minDate:now,
    disabledDates: [now],
    allowTimes:[
      '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', 
      '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00'
    ],
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      return areBothFilled();
    }
});

$('#datetime2').datetimepicker({ 
   formatTime:'g:i A',
 minDate:now,
 disabledDates: [now],

   allowTimes:[
  '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', 
  '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00'
 ],onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      return areBothFilled();
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datetime"/>
<input type="text" id="datetime2"/>
```